# How to paste stuff over a camera preview on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, augmented-reality, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I am making the classic AR app for Android.

I am using a SurfaceView to show the camera.

I want to know, how I put things over it... Currently I am using widgets, but they have two issues:

First, they are slow.
Second, you cannot rotate them in 1.5 without using view animation, and noone I asked so far (here, forums, google, irc...) knows how view animation work, so I am failing to make the view animation work in sync with the custom view that put widgets over the camera (resulting in flickering).

Thus I decided to change the method of putting things on the screen, so what other ways exist? (note I am bound to Android 1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemly it cannot be done easily, but I could put a image and rotate it easily using Matrix.

I basically placed on layout over the preview a ImageView, then I used setMatrix to a rotation matrix, and voilá, I got a rotated image that works in 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You must use OpenGL for drawing Objects over your SurfaceView.